# Apply gesture recognizer to all view components?

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uigesturerecognizer, uiswipegesturerecognizer

Is it possible to implement a gesture recognizer in a view and propagate it to all other UI components?
If I do something like that, it doesn't work:

```
  UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipe = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(SwipeRecognizer:)];
  swipe.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;

  [self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipe];
  [TitleLabel addGestureRecognizer:swipe];
  [DescLabel addGestureRecognizer:swipe];
  [_TopView addGestureRecognizer:swipe];
  [_BottomView addGestureRecognizer:swipe];
  [_ScrollView addGestureRecognizer:swipe];
  [_TableView addGestureRecognizer:swipe];

  [swipe release];
```

How can i do it?

I need to add a transparent view on my view, that covers all objects?
Or there is an intelligent way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your findings are correct re: same recognizer to multiple components, however, for the sake of completeness...

```
NSInteger count = 1;
NSInteger total = [[self.view subviews] count];
for (id obj in [self.view subviews])
{
    NSLog(@"testing object %i of %i", count, total);
    count++;

    if ([obj respondsToSelector:@selector(addGestureRecognizer:)])
    {
        UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipe = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(SwipeRecognizer:)];
        swipe.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
        [obj addGestureRecognizer: swipe];
        [swipe release];
        NSLog(@"swipe added");
    }
}
```

The only issue I forsee is if any of the objects you want to apply the recognizer to, are embedded inside more views that are already subviews of `self.view`. You'd then need to check if the found subview of `self.view` was of class type `UIView`, and if it was then to iterate through that views' subviews, etc.